# Save to Configuration Manager

Tags: c#, database

What does this code do? Thanks.

```
public void set_connection(string constr)
{
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["Mydatabase.Conn"].ConnectionString = constr;
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
}
```

ı know that it is about app.config file but can you explain the code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code actually saves the given `constr` to `App.Config` file of the current running executable under `ConnectionStrings`section.

This line opens the `App.Config` file of the current running executable.

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

This line updates `ConnectionStrings`section with name `Mydatabase.Conn`.

```
config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["Mydatabase.Conn"].ConnectionString = constr;
```

These two lines saves and refreshes the `ConnectionStrings`section of the `App.Config`

```
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

Comment: Why do we use two connectionstrings in the second line?

Comment: First `ConnectionStrings` refers to `ConnectionStringsSection` object. Second is `ConnectionStringSettingsCollection` which is a property of `ConnectionStringsSection`. This stores all connection strings of `App.Config`

Comment: More here; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: When I try to write this code in a new windows form application,  there is a red line under configuration and others although ı added system. configuration namespace. Why?

Comment: it says the name configuration manager doesnt exist in the current context.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102441/discussion-between-irshad-and-nrtn93).

Answer (score 1):

This code opens your config file of your exe at run time and updates the connection string and saves the config file back but saving the file itself is not enough for new connection string to be picked up by your exe as exe generally caches the config so calling refresh make sure cache of config is also updated